# "Underlying C/C++ object has been deleted"

Tags: python, qt4

I'm having an exception running a simple application in python 2.7 with Qt.
Code:

```
# *-* coding: utf-8 *-*
__author__ = 'luismasuelli'

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class StreamWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):

        super(StreamWidget, self).__init__(self)
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):

        self.setWindowTitle("Stream capture test")
        self.resize(400, 300)
        self.center()
        self.show()

    def center(self):

        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = StreamWidget()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

main()
```

Sh*t:

RuntimeError: underlying C/C++ object has been deleted (at the super() call line)

What could be the error and how can i solve it?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Post the full traceback error.

Comment: `.__init__(self)` should just be `.__init__()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the error! I passed a parameter (self) without noticing it. i'm a noob at that and seems that parameter is the parent widget. passing self is not only logically wrong but also an uninitialized qt object.